# microsoft team webhooks API

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm working on an web application to get meeting event. What I'm working is that generate webhooks with customized redirect url. If there is any update in meeting(such as meeting start/end, participant left/join and recording/transcript generated), the server can get webhooks event notice. But I didn't find such API to generate webhooks. Can anyone help me if there are APIs to handle it or how can I do to achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any API available for this. However, you can use Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications by subscribing to required resources.
Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked the reference but I didn't find get meeting event(only for message and chat). How do I get notice of meeting start when I start a meeting? What I know is "Get real-time Teams meeting events" in Meeting apps API references[ link is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/api-references?tabs=dotnet) but I didn't find details about it.

Comment: You can subscribe to Teams Meeting status information updates: `/communications/onlineMeetings/{meeting-id}` , which is available in only the beta endpoint. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data#supported-resources . Subscription change notifications for teams online meetings are under preview currently.
APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Comment: I only see the target url of the request, Is there any details about that?